# using variable created with for statement in python

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
for city_populations in cities:
    print (city_populations['Population'])
```

and output

```
2891000
2800000
2581000
928850
559277
287651
84554
60000
32237
4000
1700
0
```

Cities is a list containing 12 dictionaries and each dictionary has the same key:value pairs for name of city, country, population, area.  My code easily prints a list with the `population(value)` in each of the dictionaries. But what i want is a list named `city_populations` that contains each of the output items from the print method.  I thought I was defining the variable `city_populations` as a list by using the `for` statement, but that is not what is happening.  Suggestions?

Comment: " I thought I was defining the variable city_populations as a list by using the for statement" No, why would you think that? That variable will be assigned whatever is in `cities` as it is iterated over.

Comment: But generally: `my_list = []; for something in things: my_list.append(<some expression>)`

Comment: This: `city_populations = [city[population] for city in cities]`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
city_populations = [city['Population'] for city in cities]
```